# Ubuntu hangs on Freeing SMP alternatives memory

Tags: boot

have a 3 GB memory, 2 GB swap and running ubuntu 16.04. The boot hangs on Freeing SMP alternativ memory 28K ... . This is the first time boot after installation on an 2010 old amd64 notebook, nvidia graphics card and an intel dual core 2.16 GHz celeron processor.

After that, I ran a memtest86+ to check any problems with the memory, but the test passed without any errors.

How can I remove this error?

Comment: Does it work fine when you do a live session from the cd?

Comment: @KyleH   Yes, I installed ubuntu through a live sesion.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your PC battery and PC AC cable for few moments (10 minutes) and restart your PC after putting the battery or your AC. Your pc will boot completly. Try... It work for me

Comment: This solves the problem only temporarily, but it doesn't explain why it happens in the first place and how to avoid it happening again

Comment: Doesn't solve it for me, happens when I'm trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to boot into the installer by unplugging the network cable. I plugged it back in at the hardware detection stage, just before DHCP.

Comment: Update BIOS! Works for me!